# Different style for :invalid fired by required or pattern

Tags: html, css, validation, css-selectors

I have an input which is required and also has a pattern.

Can I have different style when it is invalid because it's empty or invalid because not matches the pattern?

Tried this but it has orange background in both cases

```
input:required:invalid, textarea:required:invalid {
  background-color:orange;
  border:1px solid #a4a4a4;
}

input:invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

<input type="text" name="quantity1" pattern="[0-9]{10}/(.)*" required>
```

Comment: You might want to read up on [**:invalid**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid)

Comment: The `:invalid` pseudo-class alone cannot distinguish between either of those constraint violations. The `:required` pseudo-class simply expresses the requiredness of the field, not whether it has a value.